# How to tokenize semicolon separated column value to pass to IF statement in a function in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table called 'config' and when I query it in following manner:

`SELECT value FROM config WHERE property = 'SPECIAL_STORE_ID'`

its response will be: `59216;131205;76707;167206` `//... (1)`

I want to tokenize the above values using semicolon as the delimiter and then use them in a user-defined Function's `IF` statement to compare, something like this:

```
IF in_store_id exists in (<delimited response from (1) above>)//...(2)
THEN do some stuff
```

where `in_store_id` is the parameter passed-in to the function

Is this possible to do as one-liner in (2) above ?

I'm on `Oracle 12c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-liner? I don't think so, but - if you're satisfied with something like this, fine.

```
SQL> select * From config;

VALUE          PROPERTY
-------------- ----------------
7369;7499;7521 SPECIAL_STORE_ID

SQL> declare
  2    in_store_id varchar2(20) := 7369;
  3    l_exists    number;
  4  begin
  5    select instr(value, ';' || in_store_id || ';')
  6      into l_exists
  7      from config
  8      where property = 'SPECIAL_STORE_ID';
  9
 10    if l_exists > 0 then
 11       dbms_output.put_line('that STORE_ID exists in the value');
 12    else
 13       dbms_output.put_line('that STORE_ID does not exist in the value');
 14    end if;
 15  end;
 16  /
that STORE_ID exists in the value

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong this will work incorrect in case when `in_store_id` will be only a part of some ID inside the `value` like `in_store_id` is `1` and the `value` is `123;456;789`. `regexp_instr(value, '(^|;)'||in_store_id||'(;|$)')` can be a better choice

Comment: You can also avoid regex by adding the delimiter to either side of the string and search for ';myval;'. If performance is a requirement then obviously the data model needs reconsidering

Comment: Thank you, both of you. Fixed, line #5.

Comment: @AndrewSayer good point, but still won't work in case when the ID is first or last in the value. Should work however if both `value` and `in_store_id` will be wrapped by delimiter on both sides

Answer (score 1):

If the delimited response is a collection then you can use `member of` to check if the collection contains the ID or not like

```
create or replace procedure test_procedure2(p_property in varchar2, p_id in varchar2) is
    type test_t is table of varchar2(20);
    l_ids test_t;
begin
    select regexp_substr(value, '[^;]+', 1, level) bulk collect into l_ids
    from (select value from config where property = p_property)
    connect by level <= regexp_count(value, ';')+1;
    
    if(p_id member of (l_ids)) then
        dbms_output.put_line('Do stuff for '||p_property||' '||p_id);
    end if;
end;
/
```

or do it without the collection with intermediate select like

```
create or replace procedure test_procedure1(p_property in varchar2, p_id in varchar2) is
    l_flag number(3);
begin
    select count(1) into l_flag from dual where p_id in (
        select regexp_substr(value, '[^;]+', 1, level)
        from (select value from config where property = p_property)
        connect by level <= regexp_count(value, ';')+1
    );
    
    if(l_flag > 0) then
        dbms_output.put_line('Do stuff for '||p_property||' '||p_id);
    end if;
end;
/
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e140eb40b4c3a9bd13b04fdb66680c83)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had to google `connect by` to learn what it is :) -learnt something cool. Littlefoot's answer is less complex - i'll go with that

Comment: Sure, I also find Littlefoot's answer more concise in case when you just need to check if ID is presented in the string or not. I just decided for some reason that you also need to be able to tokenize the string for some other purposes